# The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#, function

can someone help me ?
I have this function code in C# :

```
    public static int count ()
    {
        count++;
        return count;
    }
```

But, I get the message :"The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer"

Can you explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think your code means?

Comment: Is sass really necessary? learn just wanna learn. It means that `count` hasn't been defined anywhere, so you can't increment it with the `++` operator.

Comment: "etiquette" is to mark one of the answers as "the answer" when your issue is resolved.  and click the "up arrow" for posts that were helpful.  you need to do this so this question does not show up in the "not yet answered" queries on stackoverflow.  etiquette keeps this site useful and relevant and "clean", so it is most beneficial to the largest amount of people.

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare the return variable

```
  public static int count ()
    {
        int count = 0;
        count++;
        return count;
    }
```

However, I think what you actually intend is:

```
    private static int _count = 0;
    public static int CountAlternative
    {
        get
        {
            return _count++;
            /* or */
            ///return ++_count;
        }
    }
```

If that's what you intend, then make sure you read this as well:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: That's not what he wants to do.

Comment: Actually based on the increment coming before the return I think `return ++_count;` would be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because your post-increment of `count` is being interpreted by the compiler as an increment operation on your function itself.  Either you have not declared count at all, or you need to rename one or other of the variable, or the function so they do not have the same name.